# -Dio.netty.leakDetection.level JVM option is not working without spring-boot-starter jar dependency in spring application

Tags: java, spring, netty, jvm-arguments

I have a netty 4 http server Implemented.

```
public void start() {
    System.out.println("In Start method");
    try {
        ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

        b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .childHandler(new HttpServerPipelineFactory())
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)
                .childOption(ChannelOption.WRITE_BUFFER_WATER_MARK, WriteBufferWaterMark.DEFAULT)
                .childOption(ChannelOption.AUTO_READ, false)
                .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);

        ChannelFuture f = b.bind(listenerPort).sync();
        System.out.println("server started listening on port " + listenerPort);
        f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

HTTP pipeline factory class is -

```
public class HttpServerPipelineFactory extends ChannelInitializer<Channel> {

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(Channel ch) {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
        pipeline.addLast("codec", new HttpServerCodec());
        pipeline.addLast("compress", new HttpContentCompressor());
        pipeline.addLast("decompress", new HttpContentDecompressor());
        pipeline.addLast("aggregator", new HttpObjectAggregator( 512 * 1024));
        pipeline.addLast("chunked", new ChunkedWriteHandler());
        pipeline.addLast("flow", new FlowControlHandler());
        pipeline.addLast("keep-alive", new HttpServerKeepAliveHandler());
        pipeline.addLast("request", new AdvancedHTTPHandler());
    }
}
```

AdvancedHTTPHandler is -

```
import static io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpHeaderNames.CONTENT_LENGTH;
import static io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpResponseStatus.OK;
import static io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1;
import static io.netty.util.CharsetUtil.UTF_8;

public class AdvancedHTTPHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<FullHttpRequest> {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HTTPRequestHandler.class);

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, FullHttpRequest request) {
        FullHttpResponse response = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, OK, Unpooled.copiedBuffer("My Netty".getBytes()), false);
        response.headers().add(request.headers());
        response.headers().set(CONTENT_LENGTH, response.content().readableBytes());
        ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        super.channelActive(ctx);
        ctx.read();
    }
}
```

I want to debug the `-Dio.netty.leakDetection.level=PARANOID` and I set it as JVM argument [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/netty-mem-detect-demo/blob/master/with-spring/build.gradle.kts#L11). It is not working if I don't have the dependency `implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.2.6.RELEASE")`.

If I have this dependency `implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.2.6.RELEASE")` and start the server, I'm able to see resource leak related logs -

[image: Netty resource leak logs]

If I comment this [dependency](https://github.com/rajcspsg/netty-mem-detect-demo/blob/master/with-spring/build.gradle.kts#L3)  and the run the project `gradle with-spring:runMain` then the netty resource leak logs is not output in the console log.

My project is on github [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/netty-mem-detect-demo/tree/master/with-spring).

Why should I add a dependency that is not needed to make a JVM arg work. Any idea?

Comment: I would ask a question of you: why do you think it is not needed?  The evidence is that it is needed make resource leak checking work.  It is possible that another dependency would have the same effect but ... what is the problem with using this one?

Comment: most likely you didn't configure debug logging or don't bring the right optional logging dependency (like for example slf4j)